# How do I save/load Bot Framework session information to/from the local disk?

Tags: python, botframework, microsoft-teams

I have a question about a Microsoft Teams Python bot. If the bot has been added to some personal chats and group chats and I restart the bot, sometimes the bot needs to be added to the chats again. So I want to make **bot sessions**.

Is it possible to make a bot session in Microsoft Teams? I want to store session information on the local disk, and then have the bot load that data when it starts.

My bot code is very similar to [this sample](https://github.com/rvinothrajendran/BotTutorialSample/tree/master/Python_tutorial/13-HeroCard).

Thank you for your help.

**Updated:**

Like I said my bot code is very similar to [this sample](https://github.com/rvinothrajendran/BotTutorialSample/tree/master/Python_tutorial/13-HeroCard), but a bit different. Because of this I created an example for this question. First of all I create a bot in Azure and set up it.

[image: Azure bot configuration]

After this, in my bot's `config.py` file I set up the port and Microsoft app ID and password (generated by clicking the "Manage" button).

```py
import os
""" Bot Configuration """
class DefaultConfig:
    """ Bot Configuration """

    PORT = 3978
    APP_ID = os.environ.get("MicrosoftAppId", "sadsadsadasd")
    APP_PASSWORD = os.environ.get("MicrosoftAppPassword", "asdasdasdasdasd")
```

After this I execute the command `ngrok http 3978` and put the generated endpoint in the Azure bot configuration. To register the bot as an application, I use App Studio in Teams. After I do that, I just to need run the bot in CMD so I run a command like `python run.py`

After I run the bot, I can add it in the channel and run commands and functions that I created in the code.

This is just an example of how I set up the bot. The main bot is on a Linux server.

Here is why I want to make the bot keep session information and load it after the server or bot was restarted. Sometimes after I restart the bot or server it is no longer in the chat or team. In the future I want make some kind of commands and execute them using a cron job or something like that.

If the bot disappears from a chat then I can't use bot commands in that chat. For example, I add two bots in a chat. After I restart one of them I can't get any response from it like in the picture below.

[image: Conversation]

And with @ I can't see the bot.

[image: Empty search results]

I have an idea. After I add the bot in the chat I get this in the console:

```
Adding new conversation to the list: {'additional_properties': {}, 'activity_id': '123215513', 'user': <botbuilder.schema._models_py3.ChannelAccount object at 0x0000027C0ED60>, 'bot': <botbuilder.schema._models_py3.ChannelAccount object at 0x0000027Cs2FD0>, 'conversation': <botbuilder.schema._models_py3.ConversationAccount object at 0x0000027C0400>, 'channel_id': 'msteams', 'locale': 'en-US', 'service_url': 'https://smba.trafficmanager.net/emea/'}
```

Formatted:

```json
{
  "additional_properties": {},
  "activity_id": "123215513",
  "user": <botbuilder.schema._models_py3.ChannelAccount object at 0x0000027C0ED60>,
  "bot": <botbuilder.schema._models_py3.ChannelAccount object at 0x0000027Cs2FD0>,
  "conversation": <botbuilder.schema._models_py3.ConversationAccount object at 0x0000027C0400>,
  "channel_id": "msteams",
  "locale": "en-US",
  "service_url": "https://smba.trafficmanager.net/emea/"
}
```

So if I store this information and then load it when I start the bot, maybe it will work?

Comment: What do you mean when you say the bot needs to be added to the chats again? What kind of problems is the bot encountering when you don't re-add it to the chats? (I'm sorry that it's not available in Lithuanian, but [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-state) might help you understand bot state.)

Comment: For example i add bot in the chat, then from server i restart the bot, and then again i need add bot in that chat. I want make then bot starting he automatically add to the chats, where he was before rr.

Comment: I'm sorry but that doesn't answer my questions. I already understood that you're saying you restart the bot and then add the bot to the chats again. I'm asking why you're doing that. Why do you need to add the bots to the chats again? What happens if you don't? Perhaps I'm not understanding what you mean when you say "add." It sounds like you're saying you remove the bot as a participant in a Teams conversation, so that the bot is no longer a member of the conversation, and then you invite the bot so that it's a member of the conversation again. Is that not what you mean?

Comment: you are partially right. My bot in future will have some cool functions with cronjob, and then it not work if bot will be no longer in chat if server restart. And for now, are couple commands and if bot in not chat, ppl can't use it.

Comment: are you wanting to implement cron jobs to send messages to the chat later on?

Comment: yes,  i want learn more about it i,  like search new ways what i can do with bot , but before it, need found how to make sessions on bot.

Comment: I'm really sorry but you still haven't answered my questions. A bounty is no substitute for providing the information we need in order to answer your question, and it's unnecessary because the Bot Framework team is already dedicated to helping you. The problem you're describing doesn't make any sense. Teams bots have app manifests that facilitate the bot's identity in Teams and are used to indicate whether the bot is installed for a user or added to a team or a conversation. Teams has no idea whether your bot is running or not, so there's no way restarting the server could remove it from chats

Comment: @Kalakutas - Can you please edit screenshots and code samples into your question so that we can understand what's really going on? (Since there are multiple other people in this thread, you will need to @ mention me if you want me to see your reply.)

Comment: @KyleDelaney ohh, my bounty was attract more people maybe they figure some kind tricks. I try add some info how I setup bot, and how it looks maybe it answer your questions.

Comment: @KyleDelaney you see, then restart the server and wanna do simple bot commands you must tag him and then in console i can see first he add bot in the chat then execute the command, if in future will be cronjobs, bot not work at all. Because he not be in chat after restart.

Comment: @Kalakutas - Thank you for the information. This helps me understand things a bit more. It looks like you're saying that even though you normally run the bot on a remote server, you can still reproduce the problem when running the bot locally. When you stop the execution of your bot and then start it again with `python run.py`, the bot's Teams app is suddenly no longer in a conversation that it had been added to. This sounds impossible to me, so I'm very interested in learning more. It also sounds like you're saying the bot is unresponsive even after it gets added back to the conversation.

Comment: I can't imagine why this would happen either but this sounds like an XY problem. You say you want to create bot "sessions," but I don't think that would help you here. You need to know why the bot is getting removed, why it doesn't work once it's re-added, and how to fix it. It looks like you're trying to save conversation references in order to do proactive messaging. Are you talking about 1:1 conversations, group chats, or team channels? Since there's a lot I still don't understand and this comment section is getting long, you may send me an email and we can arrange a call if you like.

Comment: @Kyle Delaney idk or after restart, or then restart ngrok, but in linux server always remove from chat after bot or server reboot. So then in chat or teams you tag the bot, in console i can see the log of add bot. So if i create cronjobs, it will not work if he will not be in the chanel. then add bot to the chat is working good. I send you email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Hilton said, it's a bad idea to try and save bot state to the local disk. Also, there's no need for that. Both Hilton and I have linked to documentation that should help you understand how bot state is meant to be saved.

I cannot reproduce the problem you're encountering where the bot gets removed from Teams chats. The problem sounds impossible anyway, based on how Teams works and how bots work. Teams should have no way of knowing whether your bot is started or stopped. It's possible that your server is set up to manually uninstall the bot from Teams conversations based on when the bot starts and stops, but that would still be very strange. I'm willing to continue troubleshooting this with you, but I thought I'd post an answer now in case you'd like to award your bounty to someone before it expires.

Comment: But i think we can storage  information where bot was add, like i print console log in the question. And then bot started load chat from local ir database and auto add he to the chat.  I write you time and my contact to your email.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option inside a bot to save a transcript of the conversation, but that's kind of unrelated. Basically, the important thing to know is that you don't *need* to store anything your side - from the user perspective, the entire conversation history is preserved in the Teams client, and from the perspective of your bot, storing the entire conversation history doesn't really gain you anything - user **state** is more relevant than *conversation history*. This would be storing an object in a persistence you choose (e.g. database, nosql store, azure blobs, whatever), but it would be state you choose to store for the user (basically whatever properties make sense to store for your app, in a kind of "User" collection). This is definitely a possible and often necessary concept, and this link will be useful for you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-state?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

It's important to know though that this is a *separate* idea from sending a message on a defined schedule (e.g. Cron) to a user. For *this* to work, you need to read up on a concept called "Proactive Messaging". I have a sample on the Teams PnP gallery specifically dealing with it (code only in Node and Dotnet - no python I'm afraid, but hopefully it's useful for you). See [here](https://github.com/pnp/teams-dev-samples/tree/master/samples/bot-proactive-messaging) for that. Note that at the bottom of this link is a list of further reading on the topic as well.

Where the two above ideas come together is that you need to store certain *state* about the user to be able to *send* the proactive message later. In the sample I link to, I show how to get the settings you need to send the proactive message, but I've not included the concept of saving them to a data store - that's up to your own implementation inside your bot (e.g. SQL Azure, MongoDb, blob, whatever).

Also important to note (and I think part of the confusion and in fact part of why I wrote the sample) - your proactive code does not need to live in the same set of code as your bot! Your bot could be a web service running somewhere, and your proactive code an Azure Function/Lambda/similar.

Comment: if it help, first im create azure bot, then set endpoint and setup in config file microsoft app pass and id. Then change endpoint and load start bot who was write in python on linux server. So maybe in sql azure like you say i can store data? but its sad if i cant store it in local disk. But thank you very much for information it help a lot

Comment: storing on local disk is not a good idea because it limits your ability to scale your azure services - it's a bad design. If you want to write to "disk", then rather use Azure Blob storage - it means you could scale to multiple instances of your app running, properly

Comment: with saving data, and load it im already know. But maybe you know or can give example for how to get information about sessions? how to set up variable for it?